# CRM Dynamics 365 - Unable to create entity (WSO2 Micro Integrator Connector)

Tags: wso2, dynamics-crm, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying to create an entity in CRM Dynamics 365 (instance 9.2) using the WSO2 Micro Integrator in conjunction with the Dynamics Connector. First I created the token and referenced it in my configuration:

```xml
<accessToken>******</accessToken>
```

This works fine. However the token has an expiration time, so it should be generated automatically, hence I tried this configuration below but got an 401 error as I am not authorized.

```xml
<resource methods="POST" uri-template="/create">
  <inSequence>
    <log />
    <property
      name="client_id"
      scope="default"
      type="STRING"
      value="***********"
    />
    <property
      name="client_secret"
      scope="default"
      type="STRING"
      value="***********"
    />
    <property
      name="grant_type"
      scope="default"
      type="STRING"
      value="client_credentials"
    />
    <property
      name="resource"
      scope="default"
      type="STRING"
      value="https://***********.com"
    />
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
      <format>
        <soapenv:Envelope
          xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        >
          <soapenv:Body>
            <root>
              <client_id>$1</client_id>
              <client_secret>$2</client_secret>
              <grant_type>$3</grant_type>
              <resource>$4</resource>
            </root>
          </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
      </format>
      <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:client_id" />
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:client_secret" />
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:grant_type" />
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:resource" />
      </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property
      name="messageType"
      scope="axis2"
      type="STRING"
      value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    />
    <property
      name="DISABLE_CHUNKING"
      scope="axis2"
      type="STRING"
      value="true"
    />
    <call>
      <endpoint>
        <http
          method="post"
          uri-template="https://login.microsoftonline.com/304d868c-e271-4a91-8965-f24dedd79ccf/oauth2/token"
        >
          <suspendOnFailure>
            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
          </suspendOnFailure>
          <markForSuspension>
            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
          </markForSuspension>
        </http>
      </endpoint>
    </call>
    <propertyGroup>
      <property
        expression="json-eval($.access_token)"
        name="token"
        scope="default"
        type="STRING"
      />
    </propertyGroup>
    <log>
      <property expression="get-property('token')" name="tt" />
    </log>
    <msdynamics365.init>
      <accessToken>{get-property('token')}</accessToken>
      <apiUrl>https://***********.com</apiUrl>
      <apiVersion>v9.2</apiVersion>
      <refreshToken>0.AR8ATWbW27lO60aZ2FxDuhU8Yas</refreshToken>
      <clientSecret>***********</clientSecret>
      <clientId>***********</clientId>
      <resource>https://***********.com/</resource>
    </msdynamics365.init>
    <msdynamics365.createEntity>
      <entityType>ext_APICreateOffre</entityType>
      <bodyContent>{json-eval($)}</bodyContent>
      <queryParam
        >name,refOffre,typeOffre,commitment,promotionBeginDate,promotionEndDate,promotionalOffer,products</queryParam
      >
    </msdynamics365.createEntity>
    <respond />
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence />
  <faultSequence />
</resource>
```

**Update :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to manually refresh the token as the connector is already capable of regenerating the token if it's expired. If the token regeneration is not happening, try setting the `intervalTime` in the init operation so the token will be regenerated once this time elapses.

```xml
<msdynamics365.init>
    <accessToken>INITIAL_TOKEN</accessToken>
    <apiUrl>https://***********.com</apiUrl>
    <apiVersion>v9.2</apiVersion>
    <refreshToken>0.AR8ATWbW27lO60aZ2FxDuhU8Yas</refreshToken>
    <clientSecret>***********</clientSecret>
    <clientId>***********</clientId>
    <resource>https://***********.com/</resource>
    <intervalTime>600000</intervalTime>
</msdynamics365.init>
```

Or you can manually renerate the token by calling the following connector operation.

```xml
<msdynamics365.getAccessTokenFromRefreshToken/>
```

**Update**

Having said the above, if you want to generate a Access Token try using the following synapse configurations.

```xml
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <root>
                    <grant_type>client_credentials</grant_type>
                    <client_secret>$2</client_secret>
                    <client_id>$3</client_id>
                    <resource>$4</resource>
                </root>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg expression="$ctx:msdynamics365.clientSecret"/>
        <arg expression="$ctx:msdynamics365.clientId"/>
        <arg expression="$ctx:msdynamics365.resource"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="REQUEST_HOST_HEADER" scope="axis2" value="login.microsoftonline.com"/>
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="POST" uri-template="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

Comment: I don't have a refresh token so i need to request a new token each time .i have updated my question with a screenshot of the request and response get it in postman .I put a fake refresh token in msdynamics365.init because it's required to run .

Comment: @OussamaNairi The way you are trying will not work. The connector is written in a such a way when a certain time elapses the token will be refreshed. So although you will manually set a token to the init operation it will not be considered. One option is to not use the init operation in that case. Why can't you create a refresh token?

Comment: @OussamaNairi anyway I have updated the answer. Check that.